# LinkedIn API Attempting to Authenticate via OAUTH2 (PHP) results in ambiguous error

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

Attempting to integrate Single Sign On into the project I am working on. URL for Authentication is:

https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=#####&scope=r_basicprofile%2C+r_contactinfo%2C+r_emailaddress&state=527ac1ed0f8081.42856052&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F###.####.co%2Fsignin%2Flinkedin

Redirects to:
http://www.linkedin.com/nhome/?report%2Efailure=adZIVBnWTib4up_BiP_fhajxJtMf-QxCuI5n3xXRttZscKxS6FJjbN4qYCKWmvPauF8bvrjY0gMo-bRRTAHLnrfYYkKD-qaxjFjLbhAeRkM_cnR4Tzy5bDtRt8K5l92UN9bG

displaying the following message:
"There was an unexpected problem that prevented us from completing your request."

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a space between the scopes.

https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=#####&scope=r_basicprofile%20r_contactinfo%20r_emailaddress&state=527ac1ed0f8081.42856052&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F###.####.co%2Fsignin%2Flinkedin

-1 for LinkedIn's API quality.

Comment: That did it Josh, I removed the commas from the scope and I get the authorization screen.

Comment: Hi Josh, I am stucked in exactly same issue but your suggestion is not applicable in my case as i need only one permission: r_fullprofile and still i am getting same error as reported by @PseudoNinja. And also i have http:// in my redirect_uri Please help

Comment: For scopes, you can select it from the Developer console. So it doesn't need to send during authorization call.